# Google drive api: copy error with scopes "drive.file" and "drive.readonly"

Tags: google-drive-api, copy

My question is if it is not possible to copy a file from one folder in drive to another folder in drive with the google drive api if you only have the scopes "drive.file" and "drive.readonly"?

Tested using the API explorer: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy
The error is: "The authenticated user has not granted the app X write access to the file Y".

Creating a file (using the same scopes) and copying it is possible however.

Answer (score 1):

Figured I ask and put the answer up since it's hard to find info about the google drive api.

It is possible but you also need the **"drive.metadata"** scope for it to work. You can ofc use the "drive" scope but that provides more access than needed.